# Salvar valor em uma variável

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, typescript

Como posso salvar o valor de um cálculo feito no front-end passando para uma variável no typescript, exemplo:

Typescript:

```
valor:number=0;
```

html:

```
<ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="valor"></ion-input>
<p>{{valor * valor}}</p>
```

No typescript é armazenado apenas o valor que foi digitado no input, o que preciso é colocar numa variável o cálculo feito pelo parágrafo: `<p>{{valor * valor}}</p>`

Tentei a seguinte lógica sem sucesso:

Typescript:

```
this.result = this.valor * this.valor;
```

html:`<p>{{result}}</p>`

Comment: O que acontece no seu exemplo? Aparece undefined? Ou da um erro no console? Aperte F12 para ver se tem algum erro para depois postar aqui.